# model.fit() Keras Classification Multiple Inputs-Single Output gives error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, tensorflow, text, keras, nlp

I am constructing a Keras Classification model with Multiple Inputs (3 actually) to predict one single output. Specifically, my 3 **inputs** are:

1. Actors
2. Plot Summary
3. Relevant Movie Features

**Output**:

1. Genre tags

All the above inputs and the single output are related to 10,000 IMDB Movies.

Even though the creation of the model is successful, when I try to fit the model on my three different X_train's I get an Attribute error. I have one X_train and X_test for actors, a different one X_train and X_test for plot summary and a different one X_train and X_test for movie features. My y_train and y_test are the same for all the inputs.

**Python Code (create the multiple input keras)**

```
def kera_multy_classification_model():

    sentenceLength_actors = 15
    vocab_size_frequent_words_actors = 20001

    sentenceLength_plot = 23
    vocab_size_frequent_words_plot = 17501

    sentenceLength_features = 69
    vocab_size_frequent_words_features = 20001

    model = keras.Sequential(name='Multy-Input Keras Classification model')

    actors = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_actors,), name='actors_input')
    plot = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_plot,), name='plot_input')
    features = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_features,), name='features_input')

    emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_actors + 1,
                            # based on keras documentation input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model1.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            # int >= 0. Dimension of the dense embedding
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform', 
                            # Initializer for the embeddings matrix.
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_actors,
                            name="actors_embedding_layer")(actors)
    encoded_layer1 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb1)

    emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_plot + 1,
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model2.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_plot,
                            name="plot_embedding_layer")(plot)
    encoded_layer2 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb2)

    emb3 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_features + 1,
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model3.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_features,
                            name="features_embedding_layer")(features)
    encoded_layer3 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb3)

    merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, encoded_layer2, encoded_layer3])

    layer_1 = layers.Dense(Keras_Configurations_model1.BATCH_SIZE, activation='relu')(merged)

    output_layer = layers.Dense(Keras_Configurations_model1.TARGET_LABELS, activation='softmax')(layer_1)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[actors, plot, features], outputs=output_layer)

    print(model.output_shape)

    print(model.summary())

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

**Python Code (fit the multiple input keras on my inputs)**

```
def fit_keras_multy_input(model, x_train_seq_actors, x_train_seq_plot, x_train_seq_features, x_test_seq_actors, x_test_seq_plot, x_test_seq_features, y_train, y_test):

    s = time()

    fit_model = model.fit([x_train_seq_actors, x_train_seq_plot, x_train_seq_features], y_train, 
                          epochs=Keras_Configurations_model1.NB_EPOCHS,
                          verbose = Keras_Configurations_model1.VERBOSE,
                          batch_size=Keras_Configurations_model1.BATCH_SIZE,
                          validation_data=([x_test_seq_actors, x_test_seq_plot, x_test_seq_features], y_test),
                          callbacks=callbacks)

    duration = time() - s
    print("\nTraining time finished. Duration {} secs".format(duration))
```

**Model's Structure**

[image]

**Error produced**

[image]

*Note: Please not that each of the X_train and X_test are sequences of numbers. (Text that have been tokenized)*

Having done a little research, the problem starts in the model.compile() function. Although, I am not sure what should be changed in my model's compile function so as to fix this.

Thank you in advance for any advice or help on this matter. Feel free to ask on the comments any additional information that I may have missed, to make this question more complete.

Comment: In kera_multy_classification_model, are you actually returning the model?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro What do you mean?..I am saving it to a variable named model_4 = kera_multy_classification_model()

Comment: Sure but inside the kera_multy_classification_model there is no return statement, so it gets assigned None

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro ok let me add a retrurn model at the end of my function and try again

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro You were actually right. It worked! I was wandering what was going wrong for a couple of hours. Thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `kera_multy_classification_model()` doesn't return anything, so after `model = kera_multy_classification_model()`, you get `model == None` as your function returns nothing. And `None`'s type is `NoneType` and it really doesn't have a method called `fit()`.

Just add return model in the end of `kera_multy_classification_model()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Matias gave me the answer. Although I will mark yours as the accepted solution. But @Matias won my heart :)

Comment: It's OK. It's just not to confuse others who will see this questions and see no answers.