# Extract Keras concatenated layer of 3 embedding layers, but it's an empty list

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, word-embedding

I am constructing a Keras Classification model with Multiple Inputs (3 actually) to predict one single output. Specifically, my 3 **inputs** are:

1. Actors
2. Plot Summary
3. Relevant Movie Features

**Output:**

1. Genre tags

**Python Code (create the multiple input keras)**

```
def kera_multy_classification_model():

    sentenceLength_actors = 15
    vocab_size_frequent_words_actors = 20001

    sentenceLength_plot = 23
    vocab_size_frequent_words_plot = 17501

    sentenceLength_features = 69
    vocab_size_frequent_words_features = 20001

    model = keras.Sequential(name='Multy-Input Keras Classification model')

    actors = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_actors,), name='actors_input')
    plot = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_plot,), name='plot_input')
    features = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_features,), name='features_input')

    emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_actors + 1,
                            # based on keras documentation input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model1.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            # int >= 0. Dimension of the dense embedding
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform', 
                            # Initializer for the embeddings matrix.
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_actors,
                            name="actors_embedding_layer")(actors)
    encoded_layer1 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb1)

    emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_plot + 1,
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model2.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_plot,
                            name="plot_embedding_layer")(plot)
    encoded_layer2 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb2)

    emb3 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_features + 1,
                            output_dim = Keras_Configurations_model3.EMB_DIMENSIONS,
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = False,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_features,
                            name="features_embedding_layer")(features)
    encoded_layer3 = layers.LSTM(100)(emb3)

    merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, encoded_layer2, encoded_layer3])

    layer_1 = layers.Dense(Keras_Configurations_model1.BATCH_SIZE, activation='relu')(merged)

    output_layer = layers.Dense(Keras_Configurations_model1.TARGET_LABELS, activation='softmax')(layer_1)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[actors, plot, features], outputs=output_layer)

    print(model.output_shape)

    print(model.summary())

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

**Model's Structure**

[image]

**My problem:**

After successfully fitting and training the model on some training data, I would like to extract the embeddings of this model for later use. My main approach before using a multiple input keras model, was to train 3 different keras models and extract 3 different embedding layers of shape 100. Now that I have the multiple input keras model, **I want to extract the concatenated embedding layer** with output shape (None, 300).

Although, when I try to use this python command:

```
embeddings = model_4.layers[9].get_weights()
print(embeddings)
```

or

```
embeddings = model_4.layers[9].get_weights()[0]
print(embeddings)
```

I get either an empty list (1st code sample) either an *IndenError: list index out of range* (2nd code sample).

Thank you in advance for any advice or help on this matter. Feel free to ask on the comments any additional information that I may have missed, to make this question more complete.

*Note: Python code and model's structure have been also presented to this previously answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489625/model-fit-keras-classification-multiple-inputs-single-output-gives-error-attr)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate layer does not have any weights (it does not have trainable parameter as you ca see from your model summary) hence your `get_weights()` output is coming empty. Concatenation is an operation.

For your case you can get weights of your individual embedding layers after training.

```
model.layers[3].get_weights() # similarly for layer 4 and 5
```

Alternatively if you want to store your embedding in (None, 300) you can use numpy to concatenate weights.

```
out_concat = np.concatenate([mdoel.layers[3].get_weights()[0], mdoel.layers[4].get_weights()[0], mdoel.layers[5].get_weights()[0]], axis=-1)
```

Although you can get output tensor of concatenate layer:

```
out_tensor = model.layers[9].output
# <tf.Tensor 'concatenate_3_1/concat:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually this morning, I was thinking the exact same solution you gave me. To extract layers 3,4,5 and use np.concatenate or np.stack to merge them.